# <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Transaction failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

I was hoping that I could find an answer on the issues section but now, after 25 days of waiting, I'm posting my question here. [here's the original question though for your reference](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/34).

The first step you need to take to start with the new Firebase SDK V3.x.x on ios, is to call `[FIRApp configure];` and when I do that, the xcode console tells me that Firebase is initialized correctly.

However, no Analytics are reported from my app and I can see the following error message in xcode console from time to time.

```
<Error>: <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Data loss. Cannot record raw event. Error: Error Domain=com.google.gmp.measurement.ErrorDomain Code=3 "Database operation "execute statement" failed with sqlite code 20 and error message "could not convert floating point value to integer without loss of data."" UserInfo={FIRAMonitorContext=execute statement,20,A,3, NSLocalizedDescription=Database operation "execute statement" failed with sqlite code 20 and error message "could not convert floating point value to integer without loss of data."}
<Error>: <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Transaction failed
```

I have no idea why that happens. initializing the Firebase requires just one line `[FIRApp configure];` So, there is nothing left for me to mess with!

I feel like maybe a framework should have been added to the project but I don't seem to find what could be missing.

If you can find out how I can bypass this error message, that would be great. even if you are taking a blind guess, please share it with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news: The fix has just been released in Firebase Analytics 3.7.0. Please upgrade to the latest version and let us know if it fixes this error. Thanks for reporting!

From: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/34